# Can I safely add a switch between a fan connected to power/ground?

Tags: gpio, hardware, wiring

I've just got a small 5V fan for my Pi, but it is very loud, and I'd like to be able to switch it on/off.

Currently, the fan is just wired to 5V power and ground.
I know that I can use the GPIO pins with some other components, but could I just put a switch in the current circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no danger in adding a switch in order ton control the fan.

If you're going to add a switch in the current loop, I recommend you to do so on the loop returning to ground.

Indeed if you put a simple switch there is no problem in putting the switch between 5V and the fan. But if one day you want to make something more sophisticated like a PWM controlled fan, you will need a transistor. And this transistor is likely to be a mos-Fet canal-N. Which works better (if not only) if on the fan ---> ground side. 
*It works better because the voltage needed at the gate to control it will be less*

Hope I'm clear.

I've done it on my, which allow me to control the fan with the GPIO, even no need to touch the raspberry !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could just add a switch.